# Regex parsing citation issue

Tags: regex, pdf, ruby-2.0

I am trying to extract citations from a PDF. I confirmed that my regex worked on Rubular [here](http://rubular.com/r/zTOYp7K1Yv) but when I test my code on a real PDF it spits out some oddly spaced and wrong information. How can I fix this regex so it only extracts APA paper citations (the ones in the references section, not in-text). The APA [Examples](https://www.library.cornell.edu/research/citation/apa) might be useful. I am trying to get references from a research paper.
If you need more details please let me know. Multiple regex are acceptable for this answer, but I do need to be able to extract author, title, date, and journal. My attempt is below if it helps anybody:

```
require 'pdf-reader'
io = open('https://vhil.stanford.edu/pubs/2007/yee-proteus-effect.pdf')
out=open('dump.txt',"w")
reader = PDF::Reader.new(io)

reader.pages.each do |page|
    /([a-zA-Z.,&\s]+?)(\(\d+\)).([\sa-zA-Z,:\n\t]+).([\sa-zA-Z,]+).([\sa-zA-Z,]+)/.match(page.text){|m|
        puts "===CITATION===="
        puts "author: "+m[0].to_str.gsub(/\n\r\t/,'')
        puts "title: "+m[2].to_str.gsub(/\n\r\t/,'')
        puts "date: "+m[1].to_str.gsub(/\n\r\t/,'')
        puts "journal: "+m[3].to_str.gsub(/\n\r\t/,'')
  }
  #puts page.raw_content
end
puts"\n\n\n=======\n\n\n======"
puts reader.pages.last
```

More examples (in response to comments) [here](http://rubular.com/r/Y7tTjVRuoz) and [here](http://rubular.com/r/HXsBv6XW0o)
**THE ENTIRE PAPER**[here](http://rubular.com/r/PWLq8RLrX2)

To get these examples I ran `out.puts page.text` inside my foreach loop. Then I copied chunks of text into Rubular and tested using my original regex (above).

Comment: Never minding the regex: how do you know your input is correct? The "odd spaced and wrong" text may very well come out that way because trying to get the original text out of a PDF is a black art, and can fail for many reasons.

Comment: I am writing the contents of the file to a text file to check this problem in my code. The text file *seems* accurate, although it may not be

Comment: Can you include a link to such a text file so we are sure to start with the same input? (In addition, remove the [tag:pdf] from your question as it does not sound to be relevant in this case.)

Comment: Would you like me to post the PDF as text, or my output when I run the code above?

Comment: Please post (not too big) into your question examples of input text that causes you problems.

Comment: I added links to Rubular examples (taken from the paper).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**EDIT**

Try this one, I tried to modify it in such way, to match positions from your comment.

```
^(?<author>[A-Z](?:(?!$)[A-Za-z\s&.,'’])+)\((?<year>\d{4})\)\.?\s*(?<title>[^()]+?[?.!])\s*(?:(?:(?<jurnal>(?:(?!^[A-Z])[^.]+?)),\s*(?<issue>\d+)[^,.]*(?=,\s*\d+|.\s*Ret))|(?:In\s*(?<editors>[^()]+))\(Eds?\.\),\s*(?<book>[^().]+)|(?:[^():]+:[^().]+\.)|(?:Retrieved|Paper presented))
```

[Rebular DEMO](http://rubular.com/r/AF8BnPS6jn)
[Regex101 DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/gO9oF7/1)

The last part `(?:Retrieved|Paper presented)` could be extended with other word which could occur after title.

This regex consist two main parts:

1. `^(?<author>[A-Z](?:(?!$)[A-Za-z\s&.,'’])+)\((?<year>\d{4})\)\.?\s*(?<title>[^()]+?[?.!])\s*`
   the shared part which is matching authors, date and title:

   - `(?<author>[A-Z](?:(?!$)[A-Za-z\s&.,'’])+)` - `author` group, match    from beginning of a line, only if word starts from capital
     letter, to    avoid matching somewhere in the text, nod in
     references, followed by    letters, whitespaces, some punctuation,
     etc. You can always add some    symbols to `[A-Za-z\s&.,'’]`
     character class, if there is more    character, which can occur in
     this part of reference.
   - `\((?<year>\d{4})\)` - `year` group capture digits, if they are inside  brackets,
   - `(?<title>[^()]+?[?.!])\s*` - `title` group capture one of more of any    characters, but not parentheses, followed by character
     from character    class `[?.!]`, I used `[^()]` because during tests
     I found that its    prevents regex from multiline invalid matching,
     what also important,    this part matching is restricted by
     alternatives, without them, it    would give invalid results, so it
     is not matching independently    separate parts,
2. `(?:(?:(?<jurnal>(?:(?!^[A-Z])[^.]+?)),\s*(?<issue>\d+)[^,.]*(?=,\s*\d+|.\s*Ret))|(?:In\s*(?<editors>[^()]+))\(Eds?\.\),\s*(?<book>[^().]+)|(?:[^():]+:[^().]+\.)|(?:Retrieved|Paper
   presented))` alternatives for matching rest of content.

   - `(?<jurnal>(?:(?!^[A-Z])[^.]+?)),\s*(?<issue>\d+)[^,.]*(?=,\s*\d+|.\s*Ret))` -
     this alternative match jurnal title nad issue. `jurnal` group
     matches the    fragment beginning with capital letter, followed by
     not points (not    `.`), with lazy quantifire (match just as much as
     it is necessary to    succeed) and followed by comma. The `[^.]` is
     used, because some    jurnal titles consist commas, I couldn't use
     `[^,]` which was my    first idea, so I restreined matching of this
     part with point, which    occour always in the end of reference,
     with reluctant quantifire, it    allaws to give up already matched
     fragments (up to point) for    following matching. The `issue` group
     match digits with some content up to next comma or point, if it is
     followed by comma with digits (pages numbers) or point and word
     retrived,
   - `(?:In\s*(?<editors>[^()]+))\(Eds?\.\),\s*(?<book>[^().]+)` - this    part match reference to edited book, `editor` group match
     anything    but not paratheses (up to Eds. or Ed. key word) followed
     by title     restricted by next paratheses with pages numbers or
     point
   - `(?:[^():]+:[^().]+\.)` - this part is used to match references only    with information about publisher and place of publication,
     the    previous approuch with using a `?` on whole alteratives part
     was not    effective, because it matched also in places where
     another    alternative should be matched,
   - `(?:Retrieved|Paper presented))` - this part is for matching    references which refer to online source or presentation, etc. I
     could    be extended with other keywords,

---

**old attempts**

If you need only author, date, title and jurnal with issue, you can try with:

```
^(?<author>(?:(?!$)[A-Za-z\s&.,'’])+)\((?<year>\d{4})\)\.?\s*(?<title>[^?.!]+?[.?!])\s*(?!\s*Retrieved)(?:(?:(?<jurnal>(?:(?!^[A-Z])[^,])+?),\s*(?<issue>\d+)))
```

[DEMO rebular](http://rubular.com/r/lfpVTMdSmm)
[DEMO regex101](https://regex101.com/r/dG0cU0/1)

however if you are interested also in edited books, try with:

```
^(?<author>(?:(?!$)[A-Za-z\s&.,'’])+)\((?<year>\d{4})\)\.?\s*(?<title>[^?.!]+?[.?!])\s*(?:(?<retrieved>[Rr]etrieved.+)|(?:(?:(?<jurnal>(?:(?!^[A-Z])[^,])+?),\s*(?<issue>\d+)))|\s*In(?<editors>[^\(]+)\(Eds\.\),(?<book>[^.()]+))?
```

[DEMO rebular](http://rubular.com/r/7aaT2g02kD)
[DEMO regex101](https://regex101.com/r/hJ1eZ6/2)

Both regular expression will capture relevant values into named groups: author, year, title, etc.

Comment: This comes very close to being perfect. Using the first regex you suggest match 1 (using the entire paper linked above) fails. Every other match looks good. using the second regex matches 52,54, and 55 fail.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't understand, why `re.compile("^(?<author>[A-Z](?:(?!$)[A-Za-z\s&.,'’])+)\((?<year>\d{4})\)\.?\s*(?<title>[^()]+?[?.!])\s*(?:(?:(?<jurnal>(?:(?!^[A-Z])[^.]+?)),\s*(?<issue>\d+)[^,.]*(?=,\s*\d+|.\s*Ret))|(?:In\s*(?<editors>[^()]+))\(Eds?\.\),\s*(?<book>[^().]+)|(?:[^():]+:[^().]+\.)|(?:Retrieved|Paper presented))")` doesn't work? `error: unknown extension ?<a at position 2`

Comment: @ЛюбовьПономарева it seems that you try to run in in Python, am I right? that regex in in Ruby syntax, so there are some differences. Try to add P before named groups like [here](https://regex101.com/r/TzOHdO/1)

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a shot:

```
/^(.+?)\s*(\(\d.+?\))\.?\s*(.+?)\.\s*(.+?),\s\d/m
```

Comment: Thanks for trying, however your regex contained the paper header (which was repeated at the top of every page). Some of the regexes also contained large passages from the paper.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for all citations in the (previously) linked document:

```
^([\S\s]*?)\s*\((\d{4})\)\.?\s*([\S\s]*?\??)(?:(?:[.]|(?<=\? ))(?=(?:[^.]|[.](?:[\d,]|com|pdf|html?))*?[. ]*$)\s*|(?= Retrieved ))(.*)?
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/CLt6EvhOiM).

This allows for newlines within citations, *except* within the journal text.

Comment: When I tested this with the entire paper it only returned 3 citations, the first citation on each page. When I saved the entire paper as a string it only returned the first citation in the string.

Comment: I have changed the regex so there can be embedded linefeeds. See edit.

Comment: When I test with the entire paper (which I just added as a Rubular link in my post) this occasionally picks up large chunks of text